# Isomorphism of algebraic tori implies equal rank

Tags: lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

Let $D_n$ be the algebraic torus of rank $n$ (so $D_n = (\mathbb{C}^\times)^n$).
I want to show that if $D_k \cong D_n$ as linear algebraic groups, then $k = n$.
Here's what I've got.

We assume WLOG that $n \geq k$.
There is a surjection $\mathcal{O}[D_k] \to \mathcal{O}[D_n]$, where $\mathcal{O}[G]$ is the space of regular functions on $G$ (restrictions of regular functions on $GL(V)$ to $G$).
Some $f \in \mathcal{O}[D_k]$ is a polynomial in $x_1, \dots, x_k, \det^{-1}$ (we can restrict to $x_i$ functions instead of $x_{ij}$ since these are all diagonal matrices), similarly for $g \in \mathcal{O}[D_n]$.

So there is some equality $f(x_1, \dots, x_k, \det^{-1}) = g(x_1, \dots, x_n, \det^{-1})$ (where the determinant functions on both sides are themselves polynomials in the $x_i$ (of different rank)).

This is where I am stuck.
I think I have to clear the $\det$ denominators on both sides, but I am not sure how this helps, nor how this gives $n \leq k$.

Comment: Isomorphic varieties have the same dimension.

Comment: I'm looking for an algebraic approach to this question

Comment: What's not algebraic about it?  Get your chain of prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}_0\supset\mathfrak{p}_1\supset\dots\supset\mathfrak{p}_n$ and map across using the isomorphism.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. I meant that so far in this textbook no mention of prime ideals has been mentioned, so this exercise should be doable without this, following the approach I outlined in my question.

Comment: I mean, you then want to focus entirely on the group structure and secretly not look at the algebraic structure. Why not count the size of the $2$-torsion—it’ll be $2^k$ or $2^n$ so...

Comment: The hint in the exercise is to obtain a polynomial relation of the form $x_nf(x_1, \dots, x_k) = g(x_1, \dots, x_k)$, which is what I'm trying to obtain from my working out.